# git cl checkout from Gerrit does not find the branch

Tags: git, gerrit, depottools

I have few issues (tickets) submitted to Gerrit, as part of Dart project.

Since I am now moving to another laptop, I am able to create new issues, but can't checkout the ones already there.

Commands used:

```
C:\use\dart-sdk\sdk\> git cl checkout 212560
No branch found for issue 212560.
C:\use\dart-sdk\> git cl checkout https://dart-review.googlesource.com/c/sdk/+/212560
No branch found for issue 212560.
```

The CL tools documentation is [here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_creating_uploading_a_cl), however it doesn't mention how to checkout remote branches.

Comment: This question seems more about how to work with the Chromium depot-tools thing, so I added [tag:depottools], but that tag is little-used and undocumented.

Comment: @torek I wasn't sure about which tags to add. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this tool but it seems you need to drop the `cl` and do a regular checkout. This tool seems to be using `cl` in commands for pushing, fetching, syncing, committing operations only.
From the doc you shared:

```
$ git freeze
$ git checkout fix_typo
Switched to branch 'fix_typo'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesn't find it, giving `error: pathspec '34661_mixin' did not match any file(s) known to git`, even after `git fetch`.

Comment: @AhmedAshour could you please try `fetch 34661_mixin`?

Comment: `Could not find a config for 34661_mixin`

Comment: OK. So, are you sure about the branch name and that it exists? Small typos can also cause the pathspec error at times. I also see a command `gclient sync` which seems to beneed to run frequently to sync up repos and pre-compile hooks. Have you tried this already?